# Dotnet - Passing argument between master pages

Tags: .net, master-pages

Here is my site http://www.grandparkcityresorts.com

On the left I have a Quick search menu which is on a Master page. After choosing the values and hitting Check availability, I need to pass it to another master page without using session. Is there a way to do without session?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to think about determining the current page from the current Url. This is a good practice as it will allow you to highlight the current quick search button even if it is the first page that they load.

to do this, you would need to get the current Url on `Page_Load` and parse it to determine what page you are currently on.

The ASP.Net `<asp:Menu/>` control has this functionality built in.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5(v=VS.100).aspx